# Silverlight MVVM - Twoway binding not fired on Datepicker

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

I have Silverlight MVVMLight 4.0 application in which I have datepicker.

The datepicker is two way bound to the viewmodel. There is no code behind.

This works fine when tabbing of the datepickers textbox and will change the underlying property of the object.

But when I change the text box and don't tab off and click save the change is not registered.

I have looked at the various events that are fired and they don't fire unless you tab off

```
  private void startDateDatePicker_TextInput(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void startDateDatePicker_TextInputStart(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void startDateDatePicker_TextInputUpdate(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void startDateDatePicker_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Does anybody have a workaround for this?

kind regards,

Pat

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly sure that the `TextBox` needs to lose focus before the property is updated.

You could try handling the `KeyDown` event of the `TextBox` and update the property from there, but I'm not sure how well that would behave.

Comment: This is true and the functionality is a pain in the neck. Clicking the button doesn't move focus away from the text box. Maybe a click event handler on the button could fix it although I've not tried it and for us at least it'd have to fire before the command is executed.

Comment: A click event on the save button isn't really a good solution as the datepicker is part of usercontrol and the save is in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Change the UpdateSourceTrigger value in your binding.
If is not set, uses the default (which is the Lost Focus for TextBox.Text)
Depending the inner-workings and needs of your screen, you can set it to PropertyChanged or Explicit.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

Comment: Yes I had tried that. Default and Explicit are the only properties available and no joy.